# Arista 7050S Management port problem

Tags: arista

i have a arista 7050s and i have connect management port to a cisco 3750 and i see the port is up in 3750 but its down in arista ! here is the output from arista:

```
Management1 is down, line protocol is notpresent (notconnect)
  Hardware is Ethernet, address is 0000.0000.0000 (bia 0000.0000.0000)
  Description: Management
  IP MTU 1500 bytes
  Unconfigured, Unconfigured, auto negotiation: off, uni-link: n/a
  Loopback Mode : None
  0 link status changes since last clear
  Last clearing of "show interface" counters never
  5 minutes input rate 0 bps (- with framing overhead), 0 packets/sec
  5 minutes output rate 0 bps (- with framing overhead), 0 packets/sec
     0 packets input, 0 bytes
     Received 0 broadcasts, 0 multicast
     0 runts, 0 giants
     0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 alignment, 0 symbol, 0 input discards
     0 PAUSE input
     0 packets output, 0 bytes
     Sent 0 broadcasts, 0 multicast
     0 output errors, 0 collisions
     0 late collision, 0 deferred, 0 output discards
     0 PAUSE output
```

and i see this error log on console :

```
Oct 11 08:40:03 X-SWT PhyEthtool: %ETH-3-ETHTOOLFAIL: SIOCETHTOOL GDRVINFO (ma1, interface Management1): No such device (message repeated 59 times in 60.127 secs)
Oct 11 08:41:03 X-SWT PhyEthtool: %ETH-3-ETHTOOLFAIL: SIOCETHTOOL GDRVINFO (ma1, interface Management1): No such device (message repeated 59 times in 60.0114 secs)
Oct 11 08:42:03 X-SWT PhyEthtool: %ETH-3-ETHTOOLFAIL: SIOCETHTOOL GDRVINFO (ma1, interface Management1): No such device (message repeated 59 times in 60.1235 secs)
Oct 11 08:43:03 X-SWT PhyEthtool: %ETH-3-ETHTOOLFAIL: SIOCETHTOOL GDRVINFO (ma1, interface Management1): No such device (message repeated 59 times in 60.0148 secs)
Oct 11 12:14:03 X-SWT PhyEthtool: %ETH-3-ETHTOOLFAIL: SIOCETHTOOL GDRVINFO (ma1, interface Management1): No such device (message repeated 59 times in 60.1227 secs)
Oct 11 12:15:03 X-SWT PhyEthtool: %ETH-3-ETHTOOLFAIL: SIOCETHTOOL GDRVINFO (ma1, interface Management1): No such device (message repeated 59 times in 60.0154 secs)
Oct 11 12:16:04 X-SWT PhyEthtool: %ETH-3-ETHTOOLFAIL: SIOCETHTOOL GDRVINFO (ma1, interface Management1): No such device (message repeated 59 times in 60.1273 secs)
Oct 11 12:17:04 X-SWT PhyEthtool: %ETH-3-ETHTOOLFAIL: SIOCETHTOOL GDRVINFO (ma1, interface Management1): No such device (message repeated 59 times in 60.0147 secs)
```

here is another output :

```
sh int status | inc Ma1
Ma1        Management         notconnect   routed   unconf unconf Unknown
```

any idea how can i solve this?

Comment: Most likely, it's a cable problem.

Comment: are you sure its cable problem ? the port is Unknown

Comment: it seems interface is not available in arista, is there anyway to add it ? i think its software issue

Comment: i just changed the cable with a new patch cord but the problem still exist

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your log message indicates there is no `ma1` interface.  Either the driver isn't loaded or it hasn't recognized the management ethernet port/chipset.

This is definitely not a cable problem.

What troubleshooting steps have you already taken?  Did you recently perform a software upgrade?

Comment: recently i just do the factory reset and upgrade the eos to 4.18.3.1F

Comment: is there any way to manually load the driver?

Comment: Have you rebooted, etc. already?  `Ma1` worked with whatever software was on it previously?  If uncertain, try a downgrade.  Your hardware is supposed to be supported by 4.18.x (the last release that will work on it) but it sure looks like a bug / faulty release engineering -- unless it's just a glitch that clears up after rebooting or re-installing EOS.

Comment: i have already reboot the device its still same, do you think its related to the eos? i do not remember if its working with older eos or previous eos, but i have same

Comment: Yes, the NIC driver either didn't load, or it doesn't recognize the Ethernet chipset for `Ma1`, or there's a hardware malfunction (that's why I asked if it worked before the OS upgrade.)  You need to perform additional troubleshooting steps to rule anything else in or out.  Try re-installing EOS, preferably an older version, and check whether it works.  If so, upgrade to 4.18.x again and see if an OS re-install fixes it, or if Arista shipped a bad OS image.

Comment: its stange when i downgrade to EOS-4.9.7.swi its working but when i use EOS-4.18.1.1F.swi or newer its not working

Comment: its strange i just upgrade it to 4.13 is not working then i back to EOS-4.9.7.swi and its not working again but in past it was working with 4.9.7

Comment: Do a `fullrecover` to go back to the factory OS image, then re-check `Ma1`, and if working, retry the software upgrade to the desired version.  Here is the fullrecover procedure https://www.arista.com/en/um-eos/eos-section-2-4-recovery-procedures#ww1129030